# How to write dynamically date in sql?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a query.
It's works fine but my problem is date. I want to calculate dynamically. We are now in august. Instead of changing the date field in the query, I want to give the start and end values of august dynamically.

```
SELECT * COUNT(0) Adet
from Tax t
INNER JOIN Loman l
    ON t.Loman = l.Id AND t.Post IN (13)
WHERE STR_TO_DATE(t.dates, "%Y-%m-%d") 
        BETWEEN STR_TO_DATE("2022-07-01", "%Y-%m-%d") AND
                STR_TO_DATE("2022-07-31", "%Y-%m-%d")
  AND Sone NOT IN ('asd', 'as')
GROUP by t.Qua
HAVING COUNT(0) >= 2 
ORDER BY Adet DESC
```

Comment: mysql != (MS) sql-server. Please remove unrelated tags

Comment: I'd expect a syntax error, and other errors. Copy-and-paste issue?

Comment: Which dbms are you using? Your GROUP BY is invalid so I'd guess old MySQL.

Comment: Query just example. I don't have any issue. its works. Problem is date area is not dynamically its manuel.

Comment: A [mcve] is a great start when asking for SQL assistance.

Comment: Note that STR_TO_DATE is a product specific function. Which dbms are you using?

Comment: @jarlh question is easy. How to write dynamically this part ?: BETWEEN STR_TO_DATE("2022-07-01", "%Y-%m-%d") AND
                STR_TO_DATE("2022-07-31", "%Y-%m-%d") I use mysql InnoDb

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck? If you use this in any application, why not let the application put that data in the query?

Answer (score 1):

You can use date arithmetics starting from `CURRENT_DATE`, which is an expression of the ANSI standard and should be supported by all databases:

```
SELECT
  CAST(TRUNC(CURRENT_DATE,'MONTH') AS DATE)       first_of_this_month
, CAST(TRUNC(CURRENT_DATE,'MONTH') AS DATE) -1    last_of_last_month
, ADD_MONTHS(CAST(TRUNC(CURRENT_DATE,'MONTH') AS DATE),-1) first_of_last_month
-- out  first_of_this_month | last_of_last_month | first_of_last_month 
-- out ---------------------+--------------------+---------------------
-- out  2022-08-01          | 2022-07-31         | 2022-07-01
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `DATE_SUB(current_date,INTERVAL DAYOFMONTH(current_date)- 1 DAY)` to calculate the first day of current month and `LAST_DAY(current_date)` to calculate the last day of current month. Your desired query will be as below:

```
SELECT * COUNT(0) Adet
from Tax t
INNER JOIN Loman l
    ON t.Loman = l.Id AND t.Post IN (13)
WHERE STR_TO_DATE(t.dates, "%Y-%m-%d") 
        BETWEEN DATE_SUB(current_date,INTERVAL DAYOFMONTH(current_date)- 1 DAY) AND
                LAST_DAY(current_date)
  AND Sone NOT IN ('asd', 'as')
GROUP by t.Qua
HAVING COUNT(0) >= 2 
ORDER BY Adet DESC
```

Comment: I guess something is missing its works but original query result is 400 rows this query results 8 rows.

Comment: Original query was on month July but current month is August. It can be the reason.